# Docker container connected by OVS+DPDK, `Ping` work but `iperf` NOT

Tags: docker, ping, openvswitch, iperf

I am trying to build a platform using `Docker`, `OVS+DPDK`.

**1. Set up `DPDK + OVS`**

I set up `DPDK+OVS` using `dpdk-2.2.0` with `openvswitch-2.5.1`. First, I compile the code of `DPDK`, set up hugepages. I do NOT bind NIC, because I don't get traffic from outside.

Then, I compile the code of `openvswitch`, set `with-dpdk`. Start up `OVS` with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo rm /var/log/openvswitch/my-ovs-vswitchd.log*

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/openvswitch/scripts

export DB_SOCK=/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock

sudo ovsdb-server --remote=punix:/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock \
                     --remote=db:Open_vSwitch,Open_vSwitch,manager_options \
                     --private-key=db:Open_vSwitch,SSL,private_key \
                     --certificate=db:Open_vSwitch,SSL,certificate \
                     --bootstrap-ca-cert=db:Open_vSwitch,SSL,ca_cert \
                     --pidfile --detach

sudo ovs-vsctl --no-wait set Open_vSwitch . other_config:dpdk-init=true

sudo ovs-vsctl set Open_vSwitch . other_config:pmd-cpu-mask=0x6

sudo ovs-vswitchd --dpdk -c 0x1 -n 4 -- unix:$DB_SOCK --pidfile --detach \
                        --log-file=/var/log/openvswitch/my-ovs-vswitchd.log
```

Everything works fine, my `OVS` is working now with `DPDK` support.

**2. Create `Docker` container, and set up bridge and ports.**

I use an `Docker` image from `ubuntu:14.04` as follows:

```
#
# Ubuntu Dockerfile
#
# https://github.com/dockerfile/ubuntu
#

# Pull base image.
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Install.
RUN \
  sed -i 's/# \(.*multiverse$\)/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y upgrade && \
  apt-get install -y build-essential && \
  apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
  apt-get install -y byobu curl git htop man unzip vim wget && \
  apt-get install -y iperf net-tools && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add files.
ADD root/.bashrc /root/.bashrc
ADD root/.gitconfig /root/.gitconfig
ADD root/.scripts /root/.scripts

# Set environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /root

# Install tcpreply
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libpcap-dev
ADD tcpreplay-4.3.2 /root/tcpreplay-4.3.2
WORKDIR /root/tcpreplay-4.3.2   
RUN ./configure
RUN make
RUN make install

# Copy pcap file
ADD test_15M /root/test_15M

# Define default command.
CMD ["bash"]
```

Then, I create one `OVS` bridge, i.e., `ovs-br1`, and two ports with `ovs-docker` using the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo ovs-vsctl add-br ovs-br1 -- set bridge ovs-br1 datapath_type=netdev

sudo ifconfig ovs-br1 173.16.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

sudo docker run -itd --name="box1" "ubuntu14-tcpreplay:v1"

sudo docker run -itd --name="box2" "ubuntu14-tcpreplay:v1"

sudo ovs-docker add-port ovs-br1 eth1 box1 --ipaddress=173.16.1.2/24

sudo ovs-docker add-port ovs-br1 eth1 box2 --ipaddress=173.16.1.3/24
```

Now, I have one bridge `ovs-br1`, with two ports (no name). One is connected to `box1` (container 1) and the other is connected to `box2` (container 2).

**3. Check the connection between `box1` and `box2`**

First, I dump flows of `ovs-br1`

```
wcf@wcf-OptiPlex-7060:~/ovs$ sudo ovs-ofctl dump-flows ovs-br1
NXST_FLOW reply (xid=0x4):
 cookie=0x0, duration=130.711s, table=0, n_packets=10, n_bytes=768, idle_age=121, priority=0 actions=NORMAL
```

Then, I go to `box1` and ping `box2`

```
wcf@wcf-OptiPlex-7060:~/ovs$ sudo docker exec -it box1 "/bin/bash"
[ root@45514f0108a9:~/tcpreplay-4.3.2 ]$ ping 173.16.1.3     
PING 173.16.1.3 (173.16.1.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 173.16.1.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.269 ms
64 bytes from 173.16.1.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.149 ms
64 bytes from 173.16.1.3: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.153 ms
64 bytes from 173.16.1.3: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.155 ms
64 bytes from 173.16.1.3: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.167 ms
64 bytes from 173.16.1.3: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.155 ms
^C
--- 173.16.1.3 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 4997ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.149/0.174/0.269/0.045 ms
```

Things work fine. `box1` can ping to `box2`.

Finally, I test the `iperf` between `box1` and `box2`. I install `iperf2` at both containers.

At `box1`:

```
[ root@45514f0108a9:~/tcpreplay-4.3.2 ]$ iperf -c 173.16.1.3 -u -t 5
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 173.16.1.3, UDP port 5001
Sending 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  208 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 173.16.1.2 port 49558 connected with 173.16.1.3 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0- 5.0 sec   642 KBytes  1.05 Mbits/sec
[  3] Sent 447 datagrams
[  3] WARNING: did not receive ack of last datagram after 10 tries.
```

At `box2`:

```
[ root@2e19a616d2af:~/tcpreplay-4.3.2 ]$ iperf -s -u
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on UDP port 5001
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  208 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `iperf` packets from `box1` do not get response from `box2`.

I use wireshark to monitor the `ovs-br1` and two `OVS` ports of `box1` and `box2`.

`ovs-br1` does not view any traffic, however, both `OVS` ports view traffic. The screen shot of wireshark:

[image: wireshark: two OVS ports]

Thank you for sharing your idea.

Best wishes

Comment: I am not able to find the rules used for directing the packets example: `./ovs-ofctl add-flow br0 in_port=1,action=output:2` or `./ovs-ofctl add-flow br0 in_port=2,action=output:1`. Hence I assume you are relying on MAC learning feature. Can you check in docker the default route entry for `173.16.1.0/24`?

Comment: @jiexray Could you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is direct packets from one container-1 to container-2, then there should be flow rules stating the same. Such as `./ovs-ofctl add-flow br0 in_port=1,action=output:2` or `./ovs-ofctl add-flow br0 in_port=2,action=output:1`.

Once flow rules are applied to ensure from Linux kernel Stack you have at least default routes configured to send packets to the desired interface. such as `default route entry for 173.16.1.0/24`

Comment: Please [edit] to turn this into a conditional answer. E.g. "If your problem is ... , then the solution is to ... ." As long as you cannot comment, this is an often accepted method. In the current shape, your post risks being misread as a question.